# WPF Separate Error and Warning Styles

Tags: wpf, validation, styles

How can we show user Warnings in a similar way to Errors. The only difference is that the control e.g. TextBox needs to have a different error template and similar to Validation.HasError there needs to be a Validation.HasWarning.

In other words not all validation issues are "errors" (in our application at least). We want to visually indicate whether something is a warning or error.

Answer (score 3):

I get the need for that middle ground sometimes. Like `Command`s that need 3 values from `CanExecute` rather than `true` or `false`.

As for warnings that operate like validation, I don't know all the pieces one would need to put together, but I think I know how one would start.

You would need to rely on attached properties and attached behaviors (attached properties that subscribe to events on the object and perform operations related to those events when they fire). You might have one that governs a collection of `ValidationRule` objects to use to determine whether a warning is issued or not, much like the `Validation` properties do. You might have one called `HasWarning` that gets set or unset by the validation that can be referred to in style/template triggers.

You could make the warning display part of each control's template, or you could again mimic `Validation` and have a `WarningTemplate` attached property that is used to place the warning information in an `AdornerLayer`.

---

Since custom `ValidationRule` objects return a `ValidationResult` object in which the `ErrorContent` is simply an object, and this object is also exposed in the `ValidationError` objects as `ErrorContent`, you may also be able to use the regular validation after all. You could possibly use a class as your `ErrorContent` object that has an `ErrorType` property of Warning or Error and bind to that in your `ErrorTemplate`.

I'm not sure whether having `ValidationError`s present would prevent certain operations (such as button presses) you would wish to allow, but some sort of proxy on the ViewModel could be created that judges the `ErrorType`.

Comment: +1 for the observation that `ErrorContent` is an object, not a string.  This is a very simple way to accomplish this.  You just create a message class with error, warning, and information subclasses, and a `DataTemplate` for each type.