# How to dynamically change Validation.ErrorTemplate based on the ErrorContent in xaml

Tags: wpf

I am trying to implement what is described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296821/wpf-seperate-error-and-warning-styles/2297872#2297872). I would like to have one template for validation warnings and one for errors.  I thought I had it figured out by binding to `Validation.ErrorTemplate` in a style trigger like this:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Converter={StaticResource ValidationTemplateConverter}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" ></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

The converter simply takes a key from the ErrorContent and does a lookup in a `ResourceDictionary` for the correct template.  Unfortunately this doesn't work because binding to `Validation.ErrorTemplate` is not allowed -- `ArgumentException`

```
'ErrorTemplate' property cannot be data-bound.
Parameter name: dp
```

Anybody else try to implement something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you move this logic into a `DataTemplateSelector`? I'm assuming you're binding `Validation.Errors` to some sort of `ItemsControl` -- that `ItemsControl` can have a `DataTemplateSelector` that displays the error content differently depending on if it is a warning or an error.

If you're only showing the first error then you could always have your template include a `ContentControl`, DataBind the `Content` to `Validation.Errors[0]` and apply a `ContentTemplateSelector`

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
      <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <DockPanel>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},  Path=(Validation.Errors)"
                                 ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ErrorTemplateSelector}" />
                        <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                    </DockPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with DataTemplateSelectors, but I'll do some research and try it out. Thanks.

Comment: @John Maillet StyleSelectors and DataTemplateSelectors let you dynamically choose which style or control template to apply -- perfect for the scenario you're describing

Comment: I can't seem to get the correct binding to Validation.Errors. The Selector never fires with the ItemsControl. I put in a ContentControl instead and binded to Validation.Errors[0]. The TemplateSelector gets called, but the 'item' parameter of SelectTemplate is always null.

Comment: Are you using IDataErrorInfo to populate the Validation.Errors?

Comment: I was using a custom interface to return an object instead of string which IDataErrorInfo uses, but with IDataErrorInfo it doesn't work either.

Comment: I put an separate ItemsControl in the window and bound the itemssource directly to the Validation.Errors of my test TextBox via ElementName and that works fine, so I know the Errors are getting populated.

Comment: @John Maillet Are you getting any binding errors? I'm guessing the issue is the RelativeSource Self in the control template is wrong -- should probably be RelativeSource TemplatedParent